# why setReadPermissions is rendering NullPointerException in Facebook login in android studio

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

i am trying to integrate Facebook login into my app but when i try to enter to the activity when my button is.

I followed this tutorial: http://alvarez.tech/login-facebook-en-android/

my activity is like:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _THIS=this;
        setContentView(R.layout.connexion_layout);

        if(savedInstanceState!= null) return;

        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);

        connexion0 = new connexion0Fragment();
        connexion1 = new connexion1Fragment();

        changeFragment(0);
        connexionViaFacebook();

    }

    public void connexionViaFacebook(){
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                goMainScreen();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.cancel_login, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error_login, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

the error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.setReadPermissions(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have forgot to add the facebook initialization code in the oncreate() method of your main activity. `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());`

> In your reference link, the initialization part has been done in the class extending `Application`.

Reference:

1. [facebook android integration - Getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)
2. [Setting up fb integration - with pictures](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-facebook-integration-and-login/)